# How was this glass material made?

Tags: materials, glass

Is it possible to implement such material in a blender? If so, I will be glad if you tell me how

[image]

Comment: We can guess, but the actual answer depends on whether the glass was rendered with EEVEE or Cycles. The rainbow effect is a form of dispersion that Blender doesn't model correctly, so the shader probably has a fake dispersion setup. Here's a [Cycles tutorial](https://youtu.be/lEPZ1IUkoB4) and an [EEVEE tutorial](https://youtu.be/fiFzfY6ZVnU).  In addition, the lighting in the scene is very important to how the glass looks, as is the beveling on the model.

Comment: There are so many answers if you just searched for "[materials] glass".  That material actually looks like transparent plastic.

Comment: See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @MartyFouts could have also been rendered with a 3rd party engine, like Octane or Redshift prevalent in the advertising industry -- both available for blender (the former for free) and both often showing off this effect on Instagram. I'm unsure about the blueish tint of it though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can make (a reasonable facsimile of) that entire shape from only the material on a single (heavily subdivided) flat plane (in cycles). I'm not trying to be an ass (I swear), but this is just an example of one of the *many, many* ways to make such a material/object, and though probably not what you wanted, might be what you get if you aren't more specific with your question. Remember, there are thousands of ways to make a glass shader, each with their own nuances - it would be helpful if you could say what it is about the glass in the example image that you find unique or special. Additionally, since the effect is refraction based, it would also be helpful to know what your model looks like - for example, does it have actual thickness (mesh topology), fake thickness (like from a solidify modifier), or *really* fake thickness/depth, as in the example below. Again, I'm not trying to be mean (there is no intonation through text, so it can seem that way), but these are things to remember when asking a question to people who could interpret it any one of a thousand ways. Regardless, enjoy the shader. Though it's probably useless, I'll still post an example file for anyone who wants to play with it.

[image: LightBox]

File is here - [image]